# Kalman Filter Covariance does not increase in prediction step?

Tags: filter, system, theory, kalman-filter

I have a extended Kalman Filter (EKF) and still struggle with the understanding of the covariance matrix P, which represents the uncertainty of the filter output.

As far as I understood: in the prediction step the covariance matrix will increase due to the noise Q and the uncertainity of the prediction represented by the term P = APA + Q.

In my case, A has a diagonal form and the values of A are all smaller than 1, resulting in smaller values of P after the prediction step. Thus the prediction results in a higher certainty.

Is that true? If yes can somebody explain it to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> A has a diagonal form and the values of A are all smaller than 1

That means each variable in your state is predicted to be a fraction of its current value in the next step.  The magnitude of the variable goes down, and so does its variance (as the square).

Comment: Sorry for downvote this answer by accident.  It not allow me to undo the downvote.